# Ajax - php form with (phpmailer class) send emails automatically every day what is wrong?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi I have used this tutorial 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

to create php - jquery - ajax form , and now i have receiving empty form mails every day (2 emails every morning) even know, to access the page where the form is user needs first to login ...

so how it can be that it send empty mails every day, from protected page .... /
The form has some checks to check if some fields are empty it does not send it ... but still i am getting empty emails ...

I thinking could it be some kind of web crawlers and bots to trigger this ? since it is always at the same time of the day, with no user logins and etc (it post user login info in mail, and it is empty in these mails)

Id it is these bots how to protect it ? if no - any other ideas why this could happen ?

Thanks

```
<?php
if ((isset($_POST['Firma'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['Firma'])) > 0)) {
    $Firma = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['Firma']));
}
if ((isset($_POST['Adresse'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['Adresse'])) > 0)) {
    $Adresse = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['Adresse']));
}
if ((isset($_POST['Telefon'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['Telefon'])) > 0)) {
    $Telefon = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['Telefon']));
}
if ((isset($_POST['PostNr'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['PostNr'])) > 0)) {
    $PostNr = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['PostNr']));
}
if ((isset($_POST['By'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['By'])) > 0)) {
    $By = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['By']));
}
if ((isset($_POST['Email'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['Email'])) > 0)) {
    $Email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['Email']));
}
if ((isset($_POST['Fax'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['Fax'])) > 0)) {
    $Fax = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['Fax']));
}
if ((isset($_POST['Web'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['Web'])) > 0)) {
    $Web = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['Web']));
}

if ((isset($_POST['editorName'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['editorName'])) > 0)) {
    $editorName = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['editorName']));
}
if ((isset($_POST['editorMail'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['editorMail'])) > 0)) {
    $editorMail = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['editorMail']));
}

if ((isset($_POST['persons'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['persons'])) > 0)) {
    $persons = $_POST['persons'];
}

if ((isset($_POST['username'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['username'])) > 0)) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}

$personsname[] = array();
$personsmail[] = array();
$personsnews[] = array();
$personsmedelm[] = array();

ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
Firma : <?=$Firma;?><br/>
Adresse : <?=$Adresse;?><br/>
Telefon : <?=$Telefon;?><br/>
PostNr : <?=$PostNr;?><br/>
By : <?=$By;?><br/>
Email : <?=$Email;?><br/>
Fax : <?=$Fax;?><br/>
Web : <?=$Web;?><br/><br/><br/>

<?=$persons;?>

Redigeret af: <?=$editorName;?> &nbsp; - &nbsp; <?=$editorMail;?><br/>
Filled by : <?=$username;?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$to = 'i@i.dk'; 
$email = 'i@i.dk';
$fromaddress = "i@i.dk"; 
$fromname = "i@i.dk";

require("phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = "i@i.dk"; 
$mail->FromName = "i@i.dk";
$mail->AddAddress("i@i.dk","i.dk");
$mail->AddAddress("i@i.dk","i.dk"); 
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Encoding = 'quoted-printable';

$mail->Subject  =  "Mail";
$mail->Body     =  $body;
$mail->AltBody  =  "This is the text-only body";
if($Firma != '' && $Firma != null){
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $recipient = 'i@i.dk';
    $subject = 'Mail';
    $content = $body;   
  mail($recipient, $subject, $content, "From: i@i.dk\r\nReply-To: i@i.dk\r\nX-Mailer: DT_formmail");
  exit;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the mail page?

Comment: posted just php for send part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your server logs, check what user-agents have connected to your site at those times. Probably is some kind of a bot, that tries to access every URL listed in your page's source (also the URL javascript POSTs to, to send you an email). I bet you have your validation only in Javascript and you have no captcha?

Comment: No actually the validation is in php, but yes no captcha. I thought so to, so maybe you can tell how to prevent that ? htaacces ? dont allow to visit it ?

Comment: I'd suggest fixing your validation, some use cases are clearly left unhandled. Also, go take a look at the access logs on your server, they might reveal something.

Comment: It seems for me that validation is correct, tryed to add also Robots.txt to deny viewing that file ... will see if it works tomorrow ... ? any other ideas ?

Comment: In the above code I don't see any validation except for `$Firma != '' && $Firma != null` which can be overcome by POSTing a single space as the value (which looks empty). Add a regexp to check the email address etc. Also, you don't really need the stripslashes.